# Need float after dot first value only

Tags: javascript, php, floating-point

In PHP & javascript
I need to get float after point values only. How to get that.
E.g `1618867.7142857143` to `0.7` or `7` like this

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = 1618867.7142857143;
$decimal = $number % 1;

echo $decimal; // Outputs 0.7142857143
```

Comment: if I need only first number of after point how to get that like o.7 only

Comment: $number = 1618867.7142857143;
$decimal = $number % 1;

$digit = round($decimal, 1);

echo $digit; // Outputs 0.7

Comment: in javascript how do this